# fgets() reading only last line

Tags: c++, c, linux, fgets

I'm trying to grab a specific line out of a text file. When using fgets() it seems to only read the last line. I'm aware that fgets() overrides the previous line it had read but it seems like its *starting* at the last line and then ending.

The file I'm trying to read:

> PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
> NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
> VERSION_ID="10"
> VERSION="10 (buster)"
> VERSION_CODENAME=buster
> ID=debian
> HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
> SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
> BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"

I'm trying to get the second line: NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

int main(void)
{
    char buf[BUFFER_SIZE];
    buf[strlen(buf) - 1] = 0;

    // this line stores the command output into release.txt
    system("cat /etc/os-release >> release.txt");
    const char* fileName = "./release.txt";
    fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Couldnt not open file %s\n", fileName);
    }

    char ostype;
    int index = 0;
    while (fgets(buf, BUFFER_SIZE, fp) != NULL);
    {
        s = strstr(buf, "NAME");
        if (s != NULL)
        {
            printf("ostype: %s\n", s);  
        }
        else
        {
            printf("not found\n");  
            printf("buffer %s\n", buf2);
        }
        index++; //index is to confirm it's only reading the last line
    }

    fclose(fp);
    
    printf("Loop ran %d times.\n", index);

    return 0;   
}
```

My output looks like:

```
not found
buffer BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"


Loop ran 1 times.
```

I used the same logic elsewhere in my code with another file and it worked exactly as expected.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

int main(void)
{
    char buf[BUFFER_SIZE];

    buf[strlen(buf) - 1] = 0;
    system("cat /proc/cpuinfo >> cpuinfo.txt");

    // Read file
    FILE *fp;
    const char* fileName1 = "./cpuinfo.txt";

    fp = fopen(fileName1, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file %s", fileName1);
        return 1;
    }

    char *s;
    int numProcessors;
    int numCores;
    while (fgets(buf, BUFFER_SIZE, fp) != NULL)
    {
        // find number of processors
        s = strstr(buf, "processor");
        if (s != NULL)
        {
            //printf("*** %s\n", &s[11]);
            numProcessors = atoi(&s[11]);
        }

        // find number of physical cores
        s = strstr(buf, "physical id");
        if (s != NULL)
        {
            numCores = atoi(&s[13]);
        }


    }
    system(">cpuinfo.txt");
    fclose(fp)

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, you did not use "the same logic" in another program. Now, can you explain what exactly you expect to accomplish by forking another process to run the `cat` command to concatenate `/etc/os-release` to `release.txt` in the current directory and then opening that file, instead of simply having your program open `/etc/os-release` in the first place? Why are you taking this unusual approach?

Comment: P.S. The shown code, that allegedly exhibits unexplained behavior, couldn't possibly even compile, due to a number of obvious errors. This cannot be the real code that compiles and runs. Please show the real code that you have a question about.

Comment: `buf[strlen(buf) - 1] = 0;` is one of the more interesting bits of code I've seen lately. Please explain that one to me.

Comment: `buf[strlen(buf) - 1] = 0;` is undefined behavior, do not do that.

Comment: @user4581301 haha I read somewhere that you need to do that. Probably a waste of time but I was getting desperate. It's supposed to just set the last element to 0. Why? I haven't the slightest clue.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I can assure you it compiles(: Works great now thanks to Mr. Bacon.

Comment: For a `char` array to be interpreted as a c-style string, the array needs to be terminated with a nul character. The thing here is to use `strlen` you already need to have a nul-terminated string, and `buf` is not nul-terminated. The `strlen` could go spinning off forever looking for a nul terminator that's not there.  You don't need to nul-terminate yet. `fgets` will take care of it for you.

Comment: @user4581301 I see. So that line was essentially a waste of time.

Comment: A destructive waste of time. You're unlucky that it didn't crash your program. If it had crashed the program you'd know you had a bug. Otherwise the bug could have manifested later, leaving you wondering where the bug came from.

Comment: Can you explain how `fp = fopen(fileName, "r");` allegedly "compiles", when `fp` does not appear to be declared anywhere. Try copy/pasting what you showed in the question, and then see how well that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have inserted an extra semi-colon on the while loop line:

```
while (fgets(buf, BUFFER_SIZE, fp) != NULL);
```

This causes the loop to simply read each line but do nothing with it.  The code inside the braces that you intended to be part of the loop runs only after the looping is complete and thus processes what's left in buf, which is the last line of the file.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't see that. It works as expected now. Thank you for your help!